# How do I get an expression in SSRS report to change with a department parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

Here is the code for the expression. I want it to change with the chosen parameter, which are different departments for a company. Right now it is just set to show the "First", but I don't know what other syntax to use.

```
=First(Fields!Description.Value, "Departments")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sample data an/or an example or any other information you can provide will help. I don't understand what you want to change based on the Description, but you could probably get by with an `IIF()` in your expression.

Comment: Right now there are a list of Departments for the company this table is for, and the list of these departments are set as a parameter for this table. With the expression having "First" in it, the table only presents the first Department when it is run, even when any Department is chosen as a parameter. I want the expression to "track" the Department I choose as a parameter. But i don't know what expression to use. Obviously "First" won't do it. "Last" won't do it. I tried "All." That doesn't work. What else could there be? And why an iif?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `=Parameters!Department.Label` ?

Comment: Perhaps. Something like that. I am thinking I may need to add a new parameter.

Comment: It might help if you were to post current output as well as expected results.

Comment: Can I post screenshots here?

Comment: Yes. Or you can type an example of the data.

Comment: It will only let me post links because I don't have a reputation enough for images. There you can see the drop down of the departments, which is the only parameter. You can also see the output where it says "Austin PM Workload." It says that no matter which Department I choose form that drop down, because the expression is set to "First," and Austin is the first department. Lastly, you can see the Report Data section, with the parameters, datasets, fields, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So going back to my original solution, I think it will work for your needs. It appears you have a single-select parameter.

You would just need to enter `=Parameters!Department.Label` into your expression for that field and I think that would take care of the problem.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you! Can you please elaborate on what you mean by single-select parameter, and why this code works differently?

Comment: When setting up parameters you can set as single-select or multi-select. This may have an effect on how many results are returned. If this parameter were a multi-select you would probably need to use a `JOIN()` expression... If this answer worked for you please mark it as the answer as it may help others find this question and answer useful.

Comment: Great. Makes sense. I did upvote it. I don't have reputation enough for it to show yet, but apparently it will once I reach a certain threshold. Thanks again!

Comment: You can still mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Done! @bjones , can we keep in touch via messaging or something? I'd love to ask you more if you're open to it.